# Why are these coordinates not correct?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, coordinates

So I have a set of step-by-step instructions that are generated with erb, in each step there is at least one image with an image tag (.tagged) overlaid on top which highlights what the step instruction text is referring to. The problem is right now the image dimensions are not conducive for displaying on mobile (they have a max width of 640px). I've now reduced the images to have a max width of 300px, however now all the tag positions are incorrect. I've divided their x-y position by 2.13 (640/300) but the tags are still not in the proper location. Some are pretty close but others aren't. I think it's because all the photos aren't all the same width, but am not really sure. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

jQuery (how the tags are added)

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {                
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('pos-width')) / 2.1;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('pos-height')) / 2.1;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.1;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.1;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid orange",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });

    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)  
    console.log(taggedNode.position())    
});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {            
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('pos-width')) / 2.1;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('pos-height')) / 2.1;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.1;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.1;

    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid green",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        
});
```

ERB (how the steps are generated)

```
<% n = steps.index(step) %>
<section id="step<%= n+1 %>" style="padding-top: 60px;">
<h2 style="margin-left:20px;"> Step <%= n+1 %></h2>
<div class="stepcontainer">
    <div class="steptext">
        <% if step.priority == 1 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 2 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 3 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name } #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} Cable into the wall." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 4 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_connection.product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 5 %>
            <%= "Plug #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}" %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 6 %>
            <%= "Touch the #{step.o_connection.button.name} Button on the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="modalbutton">
        <%= render(step.flags.new) %>   
    </div>

    <div class="productimg">    
        <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>

    <% if step.input_contact.present? %>
        <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>    

        <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
            <%= link_to image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
            <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="cableimg">
        <% if step.i_connection.cord_type.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(step.i_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "orange")  %>
        <% end %>           
        <% end %>   

        <% if step.o_connection.cord_type.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>      
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if step.o_connection.button.present? %>
        <div class="productimg">
            <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
                <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
                <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>

    <% else %>
        <div class="productimg">
            <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
                <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
                <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>              
    <% end %>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check your code but a common mistake is assuming y-axis starts from bottom. It starts from top.

Like: x,y

0,0 1,0 2,0

0,1 1,1 2,1

0,2 1,2 2,2